# time synchronization on several Android devices

Tags: android, time, synchronization

Can I synchronize one time on several Android devices?
For example current time is 00:00 and through the **timeapi** (web service) we sent this time to Android1. Due to some delay we get 00:01 instead of 00:00.
We make the same on Android2 but in this time, delay = 2sec and we get 00:02.
So can we sync these time between 2 Android devices?
Maybe you suggest another way without web serivce, via bluetooth or sent several requests to web service every 5 sec to calculate average delay?
At best I have to get 00:00 time at Android1 and Android2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is the correct time on all devices, then you usually don't need to do anything except make sure that the built-in time synchronization is not turned off, and the time synchronization will be done via the NITZ protocol.

If your carrier doesn't provide NITZ time sync, you could use NTP.

If you want to have your own, custom time, turn off the NITZ sync, and use NTP with your own custom NTP server.